# Extract String between { } in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have this all of the below stored in $data .

```
'Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles' => {
                                                     'calories' => '900',
                                                     'price' => '$8.95',
                                                     'description' => 'Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream'
                                                   },
```

I need to extract the contents in between the '{' and '}' using regular expression. So, the result should be as follows.

```
'calories' => '900',
'price' => '$8.95',
'description' => 'Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream'
```

How do I achieve this using perl script?

This is the script I have so far, it reads from an xml file whether it's on the web or a local file.

```
use XML::Simple;
use LWP;
use Data::Dumper;

#request path
print "Enter path\n";
my $input = <STDIN>;
my $data;
chomp $input;
print "Path : $input\n";

if ($input =~ /http/)
{
    print "This is a webpage\n";
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => $input );

my $res = $ua->request( $req );



print Dumper (XML::Simple->new()->XMLin( $res->content ));

}
else
{
    print "This is a local path\n";
    $xml = new XML::Simple;
    $data = $xml ->XMLin($input);
    print Dumper($data);

}

print "Type in keyword to search: \n";
my $inputsearch = <STDIN>;
chomp $inputsearch;

print "You typed --> $inputsearch\n";
Dumper($data) =~ m/$inputsearch/;
$after = "$'";


$result = $after =~ /{...}/;
print $result;
```

Comment: You do not have a string. You have a data structure.

Comment: What is the actual goal of what you are trying to do? You are bending stuff around in a weird way. You are converting XML data to a perl data structure and then you are stringifying that to look up stuff. What is the desired output exactly? Why do you need that. Please give more information about **your overall goal** so we can help you figure out what you actually need to do to solve your task, instead of solving the problem you created by a non-optimal approach. Also, `use strict` and `use warnings` please.

Comment: Sorry Didn't see xml there.Although you could use this `/\{(.+?)\}/s`.

Comment: Don't use `XML::Simple`. Give use some sample XML, and we'll show you how to parse it properly.

Comment: XML::LibXML and XML::Twig are good options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, seriously. Please don't use `XML::Simple`. Even `XML::Simple` says:

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces.

I'm going to make a guess at how your XML looks, and give you an idea how to extract information from it. I'll update if you can give a better example of the XML.

```
<root>
  <item name="Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles">
    <calories>900</calories>
    <price>$8.95</price>
    <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
  </item>
</root>
```

And you can process it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented' );
$twig->parse( \*DATA );

foreach my $item ( $twig -> get_xpath ( '//item' ) ) {
   print "Name: ", $item -> att('name'),"\n";
   foreach my $element ( $item -> children ) {
       print $element -> tag,": ", $element -> trimmed_text,"\n";
   }
}

__DATA__
<root>
  <item name="Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles">
    <calories>900</calories>
    <price>$8.95</price>
    <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
  </item>
</root>
```

With `XML::Twig` you can access "attributes" via `att`, the element name via `tag` and the content via `text` or `trimmed_text`.

So the above will print:

```
Name: Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles
calories: 900
price: $8.95
description: Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream
```